# "You are not authorized to view this page" in Joomla after login from frontend login form?

Tags: authentication, joomla, authorization, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Anyone tell me why I am getting this error in Joomla after successful login from front end:

> You are not authorized to view this page

Answer (score 0):

You are probably redirecting to a page that your user (that you're logging in with) doesn't have privileges to view. Check the access level set for that page, and check whether that user has enough privileges to view that page.